# Call a children element of a StackPanel in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

for some reasons I have to manipulated some Images within a stackpanel in-code (not in XAML)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spImageList" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Canvas.ZIndex="1"  />
```

and code to manipulate images:

```
public void ManipulateArrows()                                  
{
    spImageList.Children.Clear();
    for (int i=0;i<cout;i++)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Name = "img" + i.ToString();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Image/arrow_blue.png", UriKind.Relative));
        spImageList.Children.Add(img);                
    }                        
}
```

Now I need to change the source of the images in that stackpanel, so how can i do it ?

```
public void ChangeImage(string name)
{
    spImageList.Children .. = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Image/arrow_red.png", UriKind.Relative));;        
  // Get the image by the name like "img1","img2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) method,

```
Image imag1 = (Image)spImageList.FindName("img1");
Image imag2 = (Image)spImageList.FindName("img2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void ChangeImages()
{           
    for (int j = 0; j < spImageList.Children.Count; j++)
    {
       Image img = (Image)Stack.FindName("img"+j.ToString());
       img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Image/arrow_red.png", UriKind.Relative));                
    }
}
```